# ELASTICSEARCH - Include date automatically without a predefined date field

Tags: elasticsearch

It is possible to include a "date and time" field in a document that receives elasticsearch without it being previously defined.
The date and time corresponds to the one received by the json to elasticsearch

This is the mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "entries":{"type": "nested"
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Is it possible that it can be defined in the mapping field so that elasticsearch includes the current date automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is to define an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) to automatically add a date field when your document are indexed.

First, create a pipeline, like this (`_ingest.timestamp` is a [built-in field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/accessing-data-in-pipelines.html#accessing-ingest-metadata) that you can access):

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/add-current-time
{
  "description" : "automatically add the current time to the documents",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "set" : {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "value": "{{{_ingest.timestamp}}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then when you index a new document, you need to reference the pipeline, like this:

```
PUT test-index/_doc/1?pipeline=add-current-time
{
   "my_field": "test"
}
```

After indexing, the document would look like this:

```
GET test-index/_doc/1
=>

{
   "@timestamp": "2020-08-12T15:48:00.000Z",
   "my_field": "test"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you're using index templates, it's even easier because you can define a [default pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings) to be run for each indexed documents.

In your index templates, you need to add this to the index settings:

```
{
  "order": 1,
  "index_patterns": [
    "attom"
  ],
  "aliases": {},
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "default_pipeline": "add-current-time"     <--- add this
    }
  },
  ...
```

Then you can keep indexing documents without referencing the pipeline, it will be automatic.

Comment: Awesome.
It could be possible do the same but in a index template?
I would like to do the same for the all documents indexing automatically

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, you always find the solution

Comment: Hey @val, you need to replace `"_ingest.timestamp"` with `"{{_ingest.timestamp}}"`

Comment: @vintagexav well spotted, thanks, fixed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```json
"value": "{{{_ingest.timestamp}}}"
```

[Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html#access-ingest-metadata)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29197627)

Comment: @BillTür: This is clearly more than _just_ a link; it should not be treated as a link-only answer. That said, it would be useful to offer more context and explanation.

Comment: @panda: You are correct. I’ve now fixed the URL on your behalf.